# Filling of the string variable using the function not works, if the variable is function argument

Tags: arrays, function, arguments

This code works: https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/b48w3ktx/

```
let animal = ['cat', 'dog', 'hamster',]
let dataAnim = '';                    
full_anim(animal);
$('.wrap').html(dataAnim);

function full_anim(arr) {
  for (let i in arr) {
        dataAnim += `<div class="animal">${arr[i]}</div><br>`;        
    }
}
```

However I need to have dataAnim as function argument. The following code do not works: https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/fxhpoes8/

```
let animal = ['cat', 'dog', 'hamster',]
let dataAnim = '';                    
full_anim(animal, dataAnim);
$('.wrap').html(dataAnim);

function full_anim(arr, content) {
  for (let i in arr) {
        content += `<div class="animal">${arr[i]}</div><br>`;         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let animal = ['cat', 'dog', 'hamster',]
let dataAnim = '';                    
dataAnim = full_anim(animal, dataAnim);
$('.wrap').html(dataAnim);

function full_anim(arr, content) {
  for (let i in arr) {
        content += `<div class="animal">${arr[i]}</div><br>`;         
    }
  return content;
}
```

Or you can do this:

```
let animal = ['cat', 'dog', 'hamster',]
let data = { anim: '' };                      
full_anim(animal, data);
$('.wrap').html(data.anim);

function full_anim(arr, data) {
  for (let i in arr) {
        data.anim += `<div class="animal">${arr[i]}</div><br>`;       
    }
}
```